# Why do I get the "dumping physical memory" screen after hibernation?

Tags: laptop, memory, hibernate, bsod

Lately I've been getting the dreaded blue screen "Dumping physical memory" after I try to restart my laptop from the hibernation state. I then have to restart the machine to get it operating again.

Could this be a software problem, or do I just have a poor laptop?

My OS specs are: Windows 7 Home Premium, 32-bit

My laptop specs are: Medion P6622, Intel Core i3 CPU, M350 @ 2.27 GHz

Comment: How much free space is on your C: drive, and how much RAM do you have?  Insufficient disk space relative to the RAM could cause problems for hibernation.

Comment: @Mike: Not really. The required space for `hiberfil.sys` is allocated immediately when hibernation is turned on.

Comment: But if hiberfil.sys got deleted, insufficient space would stop it from having the size it needs.

Comment: @Mike: I believe Windows creates it on boot (and it *should* turn off hibernation otherwise). The file is kept locked by the system... and, if the user has been fiddling with Unlocker, that's outside of their free tech support agreement.

Answer (score 4):

You should look at the Event Viewer and make sure it isn't a device driver that is crashing.

Often times, it will list the kernel component that caused the crash.  Unless you unchecked the "write event to event log" which is turned on by default.

Without more information from the bluescreen or event logs, this could be a wild goose chase.

If nothing specific is in the logs, I'd bank on the memory or motherboard having issues coming out of S4/S5.

Comment: I wanted to +1 three times but it won't let me. Good answer.